# Attempt to index local 'self' (a nil value)

Tags: lua

I have a problem with classes. I got below error:
Attempt to index local 'self' (a nil value)
When I call the getter method of below class.
Item.lua file:

```
require "classlib"
Item = class("Item")

function Item:__init()
    self.interval = 1
end

function Item:getInterval()
    return self.interval
end
```

I'm calling this getter function like this:

```
dofile("../src/item.lua")

item = Item()

function test_item()
    assert_equal(1, item.getInterval())
end
```

What's the problem here?

Kind regards...

Comment: Call `item:getInterval()` instead of `item.getInterval()` inside `test_item()`.

Comment: Might be useful to tell what is this "classlib". Notice you have unmatching quotes (single vs. double) in the `class()` call. And @OmriBarel should probably post an answer, instead of a comment... :-)

Comment: Thank you! What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

In general, you should call member functions by `:`.

In Lua, colon (`:`) represents a call of a function, supplying `self` as the first parameter.

Thus

```
A:foo()
```

Is roughly equal to

```
A.foo(A)
```

If you don't specify A as in `A.foo()`, the body of the function will try to reference `self` parameter, which hasn't been filled neither explicitly nor implicitly.

Note that if you call it from *inside* of the member function, `self` will be already available:

```
-- inside foo()
-- these two are analogous
self:bar()
self.bar(self)
```

All of this information you'll find in any good Lua book/tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

the obj:method is just syntactictal sugar for:

definition:

function obj:method(alpha) is equivalent to obj.method(self,alpha)

execution:

obj:method("somevalue") is equivalent to obj.method(obj,"somevalue") Regards

Answer (score -2):

Change:

```
assert_equal(1, item.getInterval())
```

to:

```
assert_equal(1, item:getInterval())
```

In Lua, it was some ridiculous for error reporting. From class point of view, the `.getInterval()` method should called with a `self` parameter, while the `:getInterval()` method is implicitly included the `self` parameter. And the syntax error should labeled in the called point, not the definition-body of `getInterval()`.

In traditional, while you miscalled a method, it was not the method's fault, but the caller.

Comment: Your answer doesn't really bring any new information in, and it's partially incorrect. *the syntax error should labeled in the called point* - it would be, but it's not a syntax error. `o.f()` is still valid Lua code, it just does something different from the colon call.